# Change data type of property in neo4j database

Tags: java, type-conversion, neo4j, cypher

I have a large neo4j database which includes various numeric information, which I would like to perform calculations on (e.g. sum, average, etc.). Unfortunately, I did not realize that Cypher does not allow type casting, and stored the numeric properties as strings. Is there any way that I can perform calculations on these properties? Either casting/converting on the fly, or some way of overhauling the whole database to convert all these properties into integers.

Thank you very much, 
 bsg

**UPDATE**
I solved the issue by writing a simple Java program to iterate through my indexes, find the desired properties, and re-store them as Integers. However, since Jatin's answer below is definitely correct (and perhaps a better solution; I just wanted to be able to use Cypher), I will accept it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually cypher stores numeric values as numeric values. How did you add them?

Comment: I created the graph using the Java bindings and am querying it using cypher. I converted the integers to strings in Java before storing them - there's no way the database could have known what they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Use the Java API instead.

```
for(Relationship r: node.getRelationships()){
   Integer p = (Integer) r.getProperty("value");
}
```

This is assuming that the `Relationship` contains property with `Integer` as property. If not,  then get the String and do `Integer.parseInt` on the String.

This is the simplest way to do it. In general I prefer the Java api over cypher. Better performance and more control

Comment: I thought of that, but like the simplicity and interactiveness of Cypher. Is there any simple way to change the data type of all such properties in the database once they're created? Or any tools for writing and running regular API queries like there are for Cypher?